# Windows Explorer does not display folder

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I opened the project, which is discussed in the article - **[Implementing drag and drop file upload in ASP.Net MVC](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-Drag-and-Drop-File-upload-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx)**

In Visual Studio / Solution Explorer, I see the Uploads folder.
In Windows Explorer, I do not see this folder.

**Question.**
Where is the "Uploads" folder?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a solution folder.
That is to say not a folder on the disk, just a 'virtual' folder within your solution to help you keep things tidy.